# JQuery Undefined in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

At the bottom of my page, I am a jquery function that does NOT do an async call. It works fine in Chrome, FireFox. But in IE8 it says jQuery is undefined. What can be causing this?

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.ajax( "dev/js/templates", {
                async : false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tpl_scripts").html(data);
                }

    })

    </script>
```

As a note, the script is being returned from PHP with header as

```
<?php 
$script = file_get_contents('/libs/scripts/jquery.1.8.2');
if (extension_loaded("zlib") && (ini_get("output_handler") != "ob_gzhandler")) {
            ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 1);
    }

    header('Content-type: text/javascript');

echo $script;
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you use the `$` variable or `window.jQuery` instead? AFAIK, these both map to the same thing.

Comment: Have you double-checked the path to jQuery? Have you looked at the errors in Firebug or some other dev tool?

Comment: Are you sure jQuery has loaded before you make your ajax request. Try wrapping your call around `$(document).ready( function( ) { })` and see what happens.

Comment: @Bruno: How would that help if jQuery is undefined?

Comment: Are you sure it loaded properly? You can check the network tab in the developer tools; the path `/scripts/jquery` looks dodgy at best.

Comment: `file_get_contents('/libs/scripts/jquery.1.8.2.js')` <= I really hope this is the answer (@user1689607 sorry updated and I don't know... coincidence?)

Comment: Also, using PHP to serve JavaScript files is a bad idea; you can completely offload this to your web server, including the zlib compression.

Comment: The full lenght of the code takes multiple javascript files, compiles them all into one, and then serves it to the client. That way its only one download of all the files to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be a long shot, but judging from your comments I have some idea what's going on.

You said that PHP concatenates multiple JavaScript files together and serves it in one go; this is generally a good idea (although I would go for static compilation and still use only the web server).

Internet Explorer is notorious for being pedantic about comma placement in objects, e.g.

```
var a = {
    x: 123,
    y: 456,
}
```

See that extraneous comma after the declaration of the `y` property? Most browsers don't care about that stuff and most PHP developers *always* use it for convenience.

Internet Explorer on the other hand bombs on this and stops running the rest of the code that follows. In your case, that could include jQuery if it was preceded by your own code (because John Resig would never make that "n00b" mistake :))

Comment: OK, I know I've left extra comma in places. Is there something can clean my code up? Or do I have to go through everything?

Comment: @DevinDixon Perhaps jslint could help you?

Comment: So that was it, the extra commas, jslint is way overkill. I used this to find the commas: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Answer (score 1):

try adding .php to the src attribute of the script tag

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Actually it probably should be /scripts/jquery.js because is it a JavaScript file. Or appears to be.

Comment: But the actual file being served is a PHP file, even though the content is marked as JS. Weird.